# MySQL - Order specific field values in multi column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have table like

```
+-----------+------------+------+------+------+
| id        | name       | col1 |col2  | col3 |
+-----------+------------+------+------+------+
```

I want order my table with two column like `(col1, col2) in (v1,v1),(v2,v2)...` and some other order.

In `MySQL` has `ORDER BY FIELD(col1, 'v1', 'v2', 'v3') DESC, other columns ASC;` but how using it in multi column like my example thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the strings.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(CONCAT(col1, ',', col2), 'v1,v1', 'v2,v2', ...)
```